# Cookie loss in cakephp when jump from one to another controller

Tags: cakephp, cookies

I am use

```
public function beforeFilter() { 
   parent::beforeFilter(); 
   $this->Cookie->name='cookie_test'; 
   $this->Cookie->time=3600; 
   $this->Cookie->path=''; 
   $this->Cookie->domain=''; 
   $this->Cookie->secure=false; 
   $this->Cookie->key='39lbkutg1i2l0kta6785d8qki5'; 
   $this->Cookie->httpOnly=true; 
}

$this->Cookie->write('log_cookie','log_value');
```

to set a cookie, it work in same controller but when i am check this cookie in another controller it not found and not echo any value of cookie.

Please suggest me with an answer........ Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button. I was going to do it for you this time but the code is also written in a single line—I hope you don't really code this way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to load the Cookie component in AppController. Have you done it?

comment all the default value:

```
public function beforeFilter() { 
   parent::beforeFilter(); 
   //$this->Cookie->name='cookie_test'; 
   //$this->Cookie->time=3600; 
   //$this->Cookie->path=''; 
   //$this->Cookie->domain=''; 
   //$this->Cookie->secure=false; 
   //$this->Cookie->key='39lbkutg1i2l0kta6785d8qki5'; 
   //$this->Cookie->httpOnly=true; 
}
```

remove this whole code should work for you.

Comment: Yes am already load cookie component
public $components = array('Cookie');

Comment: how do you get your Cookie? like this>>> echo $this->Cookie->read('log_cookie'); -  you must make sure that ‘Cookie’ is listed in your controllers’ $components array

Comment: would you plz comment all the default value you are setting on Cookie also. after parent::beforeFilter();

Comment: Yes i am use $this->Cookie->read('log_cookie') to get cookie value and load Cookie in both the controller by using $components=array('Cookie'); but it only read in same controller not in other controller

Comment: You mean like >>>>>>>
public function beforeFilter() { 
   parent::beforeFilter(); //$this->Cookie->name='cookie_test'; $this->Cookie->time=3600; //$this->Cookie->path=''; //$this->Cookie->domain=''; $this->Cookie->secure=false; $this->Cookie->key='39lbkutg1i2l0kta6785d8qki5'; $this->Cookie->httpOnly=true; }

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooo much Isaac Rajaei

Comment: I have one more question, if i am use encryption key when set cookie what i do for read exact value of cookie

Comment: what ever you write it should give you the value on read. e.g. if you write $this->Cookie->write('name', 'Larry'); when you reading it by  $this->Cookie->read('name'); it gives you "Larry"