# How to read cookie in cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-2.0

I want to write cookie during user logged in and want that next time when user open that page it read the cookie name and display before loggedin. foloowing is the code that i have used:-

```
var $components = array('Cookie');

function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Cookie->name = 'LOGIN_COOKIE';
    $this->Cookie->time = time()+60*60*24*30;  //cookie expire after 30 days 
    $this->Cookie->path = '/';
    $this->Cookie->domain = 'example.com/';
    $this->Cookie->secure = false;
    $this->Cookie->key = '39lbkutg1i2l0kta6785d8qki5';
    $this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;
}
```

in login function

```
$this->Cookie->write('COOKIE_USER', array(
                      'name' => $UserDetails['SystemUser']['Name'], 
                      'email' => $UserDetails['SystemUser']['email'],
                      'lastname' => $UserDetails['SystemUser']['LastName']
));
```

in the view I have

```
$readCookie=$this->Cookie->read('COOKIE_USER');
```

but it gives error "missing helper"

```
     Error: CookieHelper could not be found.
     Error: Create the class CookieHelper below in file: app/View/Helper/CookieHelper.php
```

please guide me.

Comment: why you are reading cookie on view? You used Cookie component but trying to read with cookie helper without loading it......

Comment: I need to show the name and email in view if user visited our site earlier.
so I have to read cookie in view. do you know how can I show the name and email in view?

Comment: Yes i know, look below for answers...

Answer (score 1):

in your controller do this

```
//Write enter code here
$this->set('readCookie', $this->Cookie->write('COOKIE_USER'=> array(
                      'name' => $UserDetails['SystemUser']['Name'], 
                      'email' => $UserDetails['SystemUser']['email'],
                      'lastname' => $UserDetails['SystemUser']['LastName']
)));

//Read
$this->set('readCookie', $this->Cookie->read('COOKIE_USER'));


//write into a key
$this->Cookie->write('COOKIE_USER.name'=>'Piya');
//Read a key
$this->set('username', $this->Cookie->read('COOKIE_USER.name'));
```

then in your view

```
debug($readCookie);
echo $username;
```

comment these if you don't need them

```
//function beforeFilter()
//{
//    $this->Cookie->name = 'LOGIN_COOKIE';
//    $this->Cookie->time = time()+60*60*24*30;  //cookie expire after 30 days 
//    $this->Cookie->path = '/';
//    $this->Cookie->domain = 'example.com/';
//    $this->Cookie->secure = false;
//    $this->Cookie->key = '39lbkutg1i2l0kta6785d8qki5';
//    $this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;
//}
```

[look at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477011/cookie-loss-in-cakephp-when-jump-from-one-to-another-controller/22477373#22477373)

Comment: i have added the comment but during login it show messgae -:-
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: @PiyaSharma As far as I know, there shouldn't be any output until the view gets rendered. Check the file and line reported in search of something weird.

Comment: I have not stuck with the error, but the "key" that is the problem, it is my security salt is indicated, but actually, changing with the digit that cipherSeed Works! !
I have resolved it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in controller

```
 if ($auth) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($auth);
                if ($this->request->data['remember'] == 1)
                    $this->Cookie->write('User', $this->request->data);
                else
                    $this->Cookie->delete('User');
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->set(__('Invalid credentials.'), ['element' => 'default', 'params' => ['class' => 'alert alert-danger']]);
        }
        if ($this->Cookie->check('User')) {
            $this->request->data['email'] = $this->Cookie->read('User.email');
            $this->request->data['password'] = $this->Cookie->read('User.password');
            $this->request->data['remember'] = $this->Cookie->read('User.remember');
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

To read cookie on controller use-

```
$this->Cookie->read()
```

To read cookie on View use-

```
CookieComponent::read();
```